# Find and rm command not deleting recursively

Tags: bash, centos6, find

We have a simple scripts that suppose to delete old folders.
The problems is that it doesn't delete them recursively.

This is the command:

```
find $PWD -maxdepth 5 -mtime +80 | xargs -I{} rm -Rvf {}
```

It removes the files and folders but suddenly tries to remove a file from a directory it already deleted.

The server is running *CentOS*, and the folders are mounted using *NFS* from the storage.

What can we do?

Comment: add `-type d` - it will target directories only

Comment: I'll try that, and get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `rm` receives a list of all the found files and directories from the `find` command. And directories directories in the list located in front of them and deleted files recursively.

I can offer two solutions:

1. Sort *recursive* `find` results: `find $PWD -maxdepth 5 -mtime +80 | sort -r | xargs -I{} rm -Rvf {}`
2. Use `-delete` option instead of external `rm` tool. `find $PWD -maxdepth 5 -mtime +80 -delete`

**UPD.1**  As sugests [@Dimitar](https://serverfault.com/users/393781/dimitar) you can add `-type d` then find will operate only with directories. It may be more fast, but in this case you don't cleanup old files in `$PWD` directory.

```
find $PWD -maxdepth 5 -mtime +80 -type d | xargs -I{} rm -Rvf {}
```

**UPD.2** As sugests [@ezra-s](https://serverfault.com/users/368782/ezra-s) you can do it without `xargs`:

```
find $PWD -maxdepth 5 -mtime +80 -exec rm -Rvf {} \;
```

And I'm think this is really best way.

Comment: I'll try that too, although -delete didn't worked so well when deleting large amount of files

Comment: Each of these options has its own nuances, so I offered two.

Comment: there is no need to use xargs, remember you can just `find $PWD -maxdepth 5 -mtime +80 -type d -exec rm -Rvf {} \;`

Comment: After some testing we used your first solutions : `find $PWD -maxdepth 5 -mtime +80 | sort -r | xargs -I{} rm -Rvf {}`  . without the xargs the command sometimes fails. Thanks @Slipeer